# Web API: xml-stylesheet directive in XML-formatted response

Tags: xml, xslt, asp.net-web-api

I have a web service based on MS Web API 2 that returns XML or JSON formatted responses depending on the request headers (as web services should).. except for certain endpoints, which basically serve up already-existing XML documents, with minor edits.  When these documents are viewed in a browser they show up as raw XML, along with the message "This XML document does not appear to have any style information associated with it."

As it happens, these XML documents *do* have stylesheets, and the stylesheet directives *are* included in the original documents.  (The stylesheets are also available via the web server)  However, `XmlDocument` objects are not serializable, so I am returning the `XmlDocument.DocumentElement` objects.  As `XmlElements`, these are serializable  but don't include the stylesheet specifications.  How can I tell Web API to include the `xml-stylesheet` directive in the request response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these "already-existing XML documents" are simply files, then I'd prefer to set up direct web server access to them.

However if that is not the case or not acceptable, I would return the XML directly as a string message from Web API:

```
public ResponseMessageResult Get()
{
    var xmlString = "...";
    var content = new StringContent(xmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
    var message = new HttpResponseMessage {Content = content};

    return new ResponseMessageResult(message);
}
```

**UPDATE**

If use of `XmlDocument` is a strict requirement then it can be converted to string using `StringWriter`:

```
public ResponseMessageResult Get(int id)
{
    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument(); // Load actual XML document

    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    xmlDocument.Save(stringWriter);

    var content = new StringContent(stringWriter.ToString(), stringWriter.Encoding, "application/xml");
    var message = new HttpResponseMessage {Content = content};

    return new ResponseMessageResult(message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks- (some of) the files do get some edits before I send them out, and I have other reasons for limiting access to the physical directory.

Comment: Also, it looks like this approach would require me to re-serialize the XmlDocument into a string? But an XmlDocument is not serializable. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: XmlDocument can still be converted to string properly. I updated the answer